# Passing a function as a parameter, and set a default value

Tags: javascript

This basic code

```
function myFun(test) {
    test();
}

myFun();
```

gives me the error

> Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function

How do I set a default value for the `test` parameter?
I want to be able to run `myFun`, without passing it any function

Comment: How do you expect `test` to be a function if you're not passing a function as parameter when calling `myFun()`?

Comment: @icecub I want to be able to run myFun, without passing it any function

Comment: Then set something like `test = test || function(){ console.log("my default function"); }` inside the body of your `myFun()` function.

Comment: What does the MDN docs say? [**Functions Default_parameters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Answer (score 1):

3 ways to handle that:

```js
// providing a fallback
function myFun(test = () => {alert('no value')}) {
    test();
}
myFun();

// check if function passed
function myFun2(test) {
    test && test();
}
myFun2();

// fail safe sugar syntax
function myFun3(test) {
    test?.();
}
myFun3();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameter.
You can do it using lambda function.
If my myTest function doesn't exist, the lambda function will be called.

```
    function myFun(test){
        test();
    }
    myFun(myTest||()=>console.log('test'));
```

Answer (score 0):

A function as default value. Snippet uses an empty function as default.

```js
function myFun(test = () => {}) {
    test();
}

myFun();
myFun(_ => console.log(`tested`));
```